# Reset DropDownListing when modal window is closed

Tags: asp.net, razor

I've got a modal contact us window that pops up, with a drop down listing where you select a category. I'm trying to figure out a way to reset the selected item when the modal is closed either by the cancel button or the x button. So far the only way I've figured out how to do this is by quickly refreshing the page (see the CloseAndRefresh function near the bottom) when either of the buttons are clicked. This is not ideal because if someone has entered data and not submitted it, refreshing will erase it all. Is there an easier way to achieve this without refreshing?

Below is the code for my modal button

```
@Html.ModalButton( string.Empty, Rxcs.Contact + " " + Rxcs.Support, "none", "HelpContactSupport" )
<div id="page-contact-form">
    <a href="#" title="Close" class="close" onclick="CloseAndRefresh()">X</a>
    @using (Html.BeginForm( "ContactHelp", "emails", FormMethod.Post ))
    {
        <div class="row">

            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && Session["PersonID"] != null)
            {
                <input type="hidden" name="address" value="@ViewContext.GetContext().people.Find(Session["PersonID"]).Email" />
            }
            else
            {
                <label for="address" class="medium-2 columns text-right">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="medium-10 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
                </div>
            }
            <div class="medium-2 hide-for-small columns">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="medium-10 columns">
                <p>@Rxcs.What_is_your_question</p>
            </div>
            <label class="medium-2 columns text-right" for="contactCat">
                @Rxcs.Category
            </label>
            <div class="medium-10 columns" id="selectParent">
                @Html.DropDownListing( "contactCat", new SelectList( ViewContext.GetContext().contact_category, "ID", "CategoryNameEnglish" ) )
            </div>

            <div id="bodyParent">
                <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Contact Help on Page: @Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" class="col-md-10" />
                <label class="medium-2 columns text-right" for="body">@Rxcs.Body.Replace( "English", "" ).Replace( "anglais", "" )</label>
                <div class="medium-10 columns">
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="body" id="body"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="@Rxcs.Send" class="button float-right" onclick="$('#contactCat').next().children().first().css('border', '1px solid #f00');return $('#contactCat').val() != '';" />
            </div>
            <a class="button inline float-left" onclick="CloseAndRefresh()">@Rxcs.Cancel</a>

            <script>
                function CloseAndRefresh() {
                    location.href = '#';
                    javascript: history.go(0);
                }
            </script>

            <br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
@Html.ModalButtonEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by clearing dropdownlist selection and then assign it's text to the first text Here is a code snippet might be help you

```
dropdownname.ClearSelection();
dropdownname.Items.FindByText(Your Text).Selected = true;
```